# Loading screen messages

Tags: fallout-shelter

When the game loads there is a message on the loading screen. Tips about how to play (eg "the longer a dweller is in the wastelands the better the loot they will find").

Is there a list of these tips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is:

- Successfully Rushing will give you the room’s regular rewards plus a
  special bonus!
- Assign Dwellers to production rooms to obtain resources.
- Rooms run on Power. Dwellers run on Food and Water.
- Dwellers with high Strength perform better on Power rooms.
- Dwellers with high Perception perform better in Water rooms.
- Dwellers with high Agility perform better in Food rooms.
- Build a Medbay to produce Stimpaks.
- Build a Science Lab to produce RadAways.
- Upgrading a room will make it more efficient and give you more storage.
- The Weight Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Strength.
- The Armory room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Perception.
- The Fitness Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Endurance.
- The Lounge will allow you to train a Dweller’s Charisma.
- The Classroom will allow you to train a Dweller’s Intelligence.
- The Athletics Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Agility.
- The Game Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Luck.
- Build Storage Rooms to increase your Vault’s Weapon and Outfit holding capacity.
- There are higher tier versions of the production rooms that are more efficient, but more expensive.
- If you are out of building space on a floor, build an elevator to access lower parts of your Vault.
- Build Medbays and Science Labs to increase your limit of Stimpaks and RadAways.
- Rooms farthest from a power source will shut down first.
- The longer a Dweller survives in the Wasteland, the better gear they will find.
- When a room finishes production, you have a chance to get bonus CAPS based on the Dwellers
- Tap a Dweller’s SPECIAL chart for more details.
- During a Raider attack, flashing resource bars means they are stealing your resources!
- When a Dweller is assigned to the Radio room it will increase all Vault Dwellers happiness.
- You can rename a Dweller by tapping their name on the Dweller information pop-up.
- You can skip 1 Objective each day by tapping the X on the Objective screen.
- If a room is full of Dwellers, the Dweller with the lowest stat for that room will swap places with the new Dweller.
- You can get free Lunchboxes for completing some Objectives.
- Confused how something works? Check the VDSG in the Pip-Boy for help.
- You can assign Dwellers to the Vault entrance to act as guards.
- Upgrading your Vault entrance will make it harder for Raiders to break in.
- Need extra CAPS? You can sell weapons and outfits from your Vault storage.
- Higher level Dwellers with high SPECIAL have a better chance of surviving in the Wasteland.
- You can sort the Dweller list by tapping on the column names.
- Tap on the resource bars at the top of the screen for more details on your resource storage.
- Your Dweller does not suffer damage or radiation when returning from the Wasteland.
- Each SPECIAL stat increases a Dweller’s effectiveness in the Wasteland in its own way.
- To quickly check on your Dwellers exploring, just tap directly on the Wasteland.
- Raiders can strike any time, be sure to have Dwellers ready and on guard!
- Radio rooms attract new Dwellers and improve the happiness in your Vault.
- A nuclear winter is cold, keep warm with Vault-Tec!
- Vault-Tec. We’ll be there! Vault-Tec.
- Mr. Handy can help with incidents and Raider attacks.
- Send Mr. Handy to the wasteland to collect CAPS.
- Opening the vault door or broadcasting from the radio room greatly increases the odds of a Deathclaw attack.

[Source: Google Docs "Fallout Shelter Efficiency Data"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit#gid=0)

[Source: REDDIT](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a0p7v/room_efficiency_data_thread/)