# Where can I read all of the loading screen tips in-game?

Tags: fallout-shelter

For Fallout Shelter I've seen a lot of helpful tips flash by on the loading screens, but haven't found a log or list of them in the options menu in the game so I can read through all the tips.

I've checked the Survival guide that has 22 pages in-game, but it doesn't have those nifty tips I keep seeing, like "Rooms furthest away from a power generator will get shut off first (when you run out of energy)"

Is there anyway to read all of the loading screen tips anywhere in-game?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227734/loading-screen-messages?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full list of all the tips are below. Credit to doc at [docpop.org](http://www.docpop.org/2015/06/loading-screen-tips-from-fallout-shelter-for-ios/) for braking into the code to compile the list.

- Successfully Rushing will give you the room’s regular rewards plus a special bonus!
- Assign Dwellers to production rooms to obtain resources.
- Rooms run on Power. Dwellers run on Food and Water.
- Dwellers with high Strength perform better on Power rooms.
- Dwellers with high Perception perform better in Water rooms.
- Dwellers with high Agility perform better in Food rooms.
- Build a Medbay to produce Stimpaks.
- Build a Science Lab to produce RadAways.
- Upgrading a room will make it more efficient and give you more storage.
- The Weight Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Strength.
- The Armory room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Perception.
- The Fitness Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Endurance.
- The Lounge will allow you to train a Dweller’s Charisma.
- The Classroom will allow you to train a Dweller’s Intelligence.
- The Athletics Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Agility.
- Successfully Rushing will give you the room’s regular rewards plus a special bonus!
- The Game Room will allow you to train a Dweller’s Luck.
- Build Storage Rooms to increase your Vault’s Weapon and Outfit holding capacity.
- There are higher tier versions of the production rooms that are more efficient, but more expensive.
- If you are out of building space on a floor, build an elevator to access lower parts of your Vault.
- Build Medbays and Science Labs to increase your limit of Stimpaks and RadAways.
- Rooms farthest from a power source will shut down first.
- The longer a Dweller survives in the Wasteland, the better gear they will find.
- When a room finishes production, you have a chance to get bonus CAPS based on the Dwellers
- Tap a Dweller’s SPECIAL chart for more details.
- During a Raider attack, flashing resource bars means they are stealing your resources!
- When a Dweller is assigned to the Radio room it will increase all Vault Dwellers happiness.
- You can rename a Dweller by tapping their name on the Dweller information pop-up.
- You can skip 1 Objective each day by tapping the X on the Objective screen.
- If a room is full of Dwellers, the Dweller with the lowest stat for that room will swap places with the new Dweller.
- You can get free Lunchboxes for completing some Objectives.
- Confused how something works? Check the VDSG in the Pip-Boy for help.
- You can assign Dwellers to the Vault entrance to act as guards.
- Upgrading your Vault entrance will make it harder for Raiders to break in.
- Need extra CAPS? You can sell weapons and outfits from your Vault storage.
- Higher level Dwellers with high SPECIAL have a better chance of surviving in the Wasteland.
- You can sort the Dweller list by tapping on the column names.
- Tap on the resource bars at the top of the screen for more details on your resource storage.
- Your Dweller does not suffer damage or radiation when returning from the Wasteland.
- Each SPECIAL stat increases a Dweller’s effectiveness in the Wasteland in its own way.
- To quickly check on your Dwellers exploring, just tap directly on the Wasteland.
- Raiders can strike any time, be sure to have Dwellers ready and on guard!
- Radio rooms attract new Dwellers and improve the happiness in your Vault.
- A nuclear winter is cold, keep warm with Vault-Tec!
- Vault-Tec. We’ll be there! Vault-Tec.

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks to me like a valid answer, even though I don't play Fallout Shelter.

Comment: I would suspect the users are downvoting the question, and downvoting the answer for being here. Technically OP is asking where you can read the tips. While posting them here does not technically answer the question, it answers the request. Had OP originally asked for a list of what comes up, some users might consider it off topic. Some would consider needing any answer to this extent to be too broad.

Comment: @Timelord64 This question and answer are duplicates.. That is all.

Comment: @James This answer's not a duplicate, it has 4 more than in the other question. and different source

Comment: @Aequitas, the question itself is the duplicate. Generally, not the type of thing that should get the answer downvoted, but consider that if this question is deleted, so is your answer. When I find I have answered to duplicates, I delete my answer, and re post it on the original. If your adding to the original answer, I would recommend doing so. Reaches more viewers that way